# How to use an array to display a form?

Tags: php, arrays, function

I am currently trying to create a register page but I am required to use an array of arrays to create a function to use to create a form. But I don't know how to do that exactly.

```
display_form(
array(
  array(
    "type" => "text",
    "name" => "first_name",
    "value" => "",
    "label" => "First Name"
  ),
  array(
    "type" => "text",
    "name" => "last_name",
    "value" => "",
    "label" => "Last Name"
  ),
  array(
    "type" => "email",
    "name" => "email",
    "value" => "",
    "label" => "Email"
  ),
  array(
    "type" => "number",
    "name" => "extension",
    "value" => "",
    "label" => "Extension"
  )
 )
);
```

This I need to make into a function to use it for making multiple forms on different pages but I don't understand how to call that function and actually display the form.
If anyone could provide some insight that will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not clear what you expect but maybe something like this will help you:

```
function display_form($fields) {
    foreach ($fields as $field) {?>
    <label><?=$field['label']?>
        <input type="<?=$field['type']?>" name="<?=$field['name']?>" value="<?=$field['value']?>" />
    </label>
<?php    
    }    
}
```

Fiddle [here](https://3v4l.org/I8ujs)

Comment: Oh my god thank you! I have been trying to figure this out for ages